# What is import java.util.UUID used for?

Tags: java, import, unique, uuid, reasoning

```
import java.util.UUID
public class Person implements Serializable {

        private UUID uuid;

        public Person() {
            uuid = UUID.fromString("3856c3da-ea56-4717-9f58-85f6c5f560a5");
        }

        public UUID getUuid() {
            return uuid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It helps you parse/generate a [`Universally unique identifier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) .

Comment: What is the use of it? Why do we use it in our domain model

Comment: Its a `unique` number, you can use it to differentiate between users etc.

Comment: In the example, all UUIDs are identical. :P

Comment: @Peter someone should submit it to the TheDailyWTF then :P

Comment: this example is particularly weird. If this is inside a real application probably is that the class Person shouldn't be used in the system. So by default it points to a non definded person (user nobody or something like that) in the database. Otherwise, I don't find an explanation for this.